# Populate jTable with MySQL database syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a JInternalFrame called Servicos.java with this code:

```
MySqlDAO sqlDAO = new MySqlDAO();
Connection conexao = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

public Servicos() {
    initComponents();
    conexao = sqlDAO.conector();


}

private void procurar(){
    String sql = "select * from servicos where in like ?";
    try{
        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, in.getText()+"%");
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void inKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    procurar();
}
```

When I run the app I get this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in like '%'' at line 1

Comment: your query is not correct. is `in` the field you're looking in or the operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a SQL syntax error in:

```
select * from servicos where in like ?
```

your request should be:

```
select * from servicos where <columnName> like ?
```

You cannot use `in` directly as a column name because it is a reserved keyword. If you want to use it you have to escape it with backquotes :

```
select * from servicos where `in` like ?
```

Answer (score 2):

The operator is `like`, not `in like`. If your column is actually named "in", you should escape it:

```
String sql = "select * from servicos where `in` like ?";
// Here -----------------------------------^
```

Comment: or *qualify* the column reference with the table name (or alias) ... `WHERE servicos.in LIKE ...` either way (escaping or qualifying) avoids the parser seeing the token `in` as the reserved word `IN`.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html